# How to get the active tab name or id using java?

Tags: java, html, tabs

Below is my html code inside a jsp for creating tabs.

```
<form name="form1" action="/SampleServlet" method="post">
<ul id="navigation">
<li><a id="tab1" name="live" class="selected" onclick="parent.frame1.location='frame1.jsp'">LIVE</a></li>
<li><a id="tab2" name="history" onclick="parent.frame1.location='frame2.jsp'">HISTORY</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now I want the selected tab or activated tab name or id in my servlet.How can I use

```
request.getParameter("")
```

method for getting the selected or activated tab?please help me.I found some solutions using jquery but I don't want to use Jquery.Please help me.How can I get the tab name or id or value which is selected at present or activated at present using  **request.getParameter()?**

Comment: how are you calling your servlet?

Comment: Why you don't want to use jQuery?

Comment: Atleast give both the tabs a different Id, that makes sense, if you want to find out which tab is selected or clicked

Comment: Sorry..Please see edited post

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you did not use duplicate id eg: Change second link id to tab2

```
<ul id="navigation">
<li><a id="tab1" name="live" class="selected" onclick="parent.frame1.location='frame1.jsp'">LIVE</a></li>
<li><a id="tab2" name="live" class="selected" onclick="parent.frame1.location='frame2.jsp'">HISTORY</a></li>
</ul>
```

you try to use `request.getparametervalues()`

Comment: request.getParameter() should take the input parameter right?So what should I take request.getParameter("id"); it is not giving result if I select tab2.

Comment: better use jQUery>> jQuery(".selected").click(function(){
});

Comment: he should go with jQuery, .click() is so easy to do this!

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery! It will make your work easier! Just register a click handler on these tabs, and send an ajax request to servlet with parameter as your tab ID, so simple! Below is the code:

assuming: Tab1: ID='tab1', CLASS='tab'
Tab2: ID='tab2', CLASS='tab'

```
// click handler
$('.tab').click(function(){
  // get tab id
  var id = $(this).attr('id');

  // now send an ajax request to servlet with parameter which stores this id value
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',  // request type
    data: {param: id},
    url: '/servleturl',
    dataType: 'text',  // or json or any other which your servlet will return

    // this will be executed when request is successful and a correct response is recieved
    success: function(response){
      alert(response); // or do whatever you like to do with response
    },

    // this function will be executed when there is any error
    error: function(){

    },

    // this will be always executed, like a finally block in Java
    complete: function(){

    },
  });
});
```

You may omit the error and complete functions; I have told you all the necessary stuff. It is so simple.

In order to receive the ID in servlet you use:

```
String tabId = request.getParameter('param');
```

'param', because I have specified:

```
data: {param: id}
```

If you use any other name than 'param', use that instead.

In order to send response from servlet, simply use:

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.write("ABCD or whatever you want");
out.close();  // DON'T forget this!
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be hard to select it without jQuery, you have to iterate all the `a` elements to find it (or some other iteration will be necessary).

1. You have to find the `a` with "selected" class and read it's ID (which is `$("a.selected").attr('id')` in jQuery). There is no "getElementByClass" in core JS...
2. In both cases you have to set this value to a hidden form element, which has to be added to the `<form>` as follow: `<input type="hidden" name="activetab"></input>`
3. And then you will find it in the servlet with `request.getParameter("activetab")`.

Anyway this is a core Javascript solution: http://jsfiddle.net/balintbako/NdNqX/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setTabAndSubmit() {
        var tab;
        var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
        for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
            if (anchors[i].className == 'selected') {
                tab = anchors[i].id;
                break;
            }
        }
        document.forms["myform"].elements["activetab"].value = tab;
        alert(tab);
    }
</script>
<form name="myform" action="/path" onSubmit="setTabAndSubmit()">
    <input name="activetab" type="hidden"></input>
    <input name="somefield" type="text"></input>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
</form> 
<a id="a1" href="#" class="selected">link 1</a>
<a id="a2" href="#">link 2</a>
```

Comment: I did not get you.Please explain me.What is "You have to select the a with "selected" class and read it's ID "? please help me

Comment: Why to use this thing, using hidden element, and all when using jQUery this thing is a piece of cake! Is the code which I have given you seems difficult to you? Are you comfortable with JavaScript or not?

Comment: I changed to wording: select means you have to find it with a "css selector"

Comment: @stalin I'm not sure that the thing you wrote is the goal here. You send an ajax request, which is not the same as posting a form. We see 4 rows from the page and the rest might not be ajax ready....

Comment: He does not want to submit the form. After reading the ques what I infer is that, he is creating two tabs inside his form and based on tab selection, he wants to show different form fields. Clicking on tab is no way related to form submission!

Comment: I was maybe misleading... What I wanted to say, is that as tabs are redirecting, you can find out the tab from the URL.

Comment: @BalintBako: If he wants to submit the form, then submitting the 'tabId' stored in hidden element in the form as you told, is a good idea.

Comment: actually he has not specified this in the question so this is still a guess. From ques it seems he just want to send the selected tab's 'ID' to the servlet and for that ajax is a better option bec doing this without reloading the page makes sense.

Comment: That is true, however if I were him I wanted to send some other data too, not only a tabid :)

Comment: Here I do not want to submit the form.I just click on tab and corresponding page will be displayed.And I want to know which tab is in active at present in servlet.

Comment: And what would you like to do with that info? I'm even less sure now. You have to send to the Servlet somehow. You can do it my way or as @stalin wrote it, but that won't change a thing on the current page. If you just simply want to know what was clicked and do something which doesn't affect the current page, then stalin's answer is great for you (jquery though).